# Inequality question(wish to confirm working)

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a_{i}$ be a set of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}^3=3$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}^5=5$.
Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i} > \frac{3}{2}$.

My attempt: Using Titu's lemma,
$$\frac{a_{1}^6}{a_{1}} + \frac{a_{2}^6}{a_{2}} + \cdots \ge \frac{(a_{1}^3 + a_{2}^3+\cdots)^2}{a_{1} + a_{2}+\cdots} \, ,$$
giving
$$5 \ge \frac{3^2}{a_{1} + a_{2}+..}\, .$$

Hence $a_{1} + a_{2}+ \cdots \ge  \frac 9 5 > \frac 3 2$.

I wish to confirm if what I did is correct? The question wanted me to prove it to be greater than $3/2$, while I got for $9/5$. If this is correct, is there any alternative method to arrive at greater than $3/2$ directly?

Comment: Your reasoning looks fine to me.

Comment: Your method works good and does not involve hefty manipulations. Even if some method arrived at 3/2 directly, I don't see how it could be simpler than this.

Comment: @DS How about this approach: Clearly, we have $x_i \le \sqrt[5]{5} < \sqrt{2}, \forall i$.
Thus, we have $x_i \ge \frac12 x_i^3, \forall i$.
Thus, we have
$\sum_{i} x_i \ge \frac12 \sum_{i} x_i^3 = \frac32$.

Comment: @RiverLi The C-S used by the OP is more obvious that $\sqrt[5]5 < \sqrt 2$, imo

Comment: It seems that the minimum is $$3\cdot \frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{\alpha^2\beta^2} -  \frac{5}{\alpha^2\beta^2} \approx 2.1368..$$ where $(\alpha,\beta)=(1.36.., 0.77...)$ are two real solution of $\cases{x^3 + y^3 =3\\x^5 + y^5  = 5}$

Comment: @DS It is $5^2 < 2^5$. Is it understandable by kids? Some kids don't know/learn C-S.

Comment: @RiverLi by obvious I meant what comes to mind when we see the problem. But yes, your approach is very simple too, and should be added as an answer

Comment: @DS Fine. Both are simple.